# NSPasteboardType of dragged keychain item

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop

I want to create an NSView which will accept dragged items from the KeychainAccess app (for example a certificate).
Dragging a certificate to the desktop results in a file, so I think it should be possible to receive them in my NSView as well. I know the basic concept of drag and drop in Cocoa and searched / tried a lot already, but I really don't know how to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Jodocus